# Who or what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

The answer to the riddle is two words.

The Riddle:

> I grow by consuming one thing
>
> The more I consume the larger I get
>
> Regardless of my size you don't see more of me
>
> I am lighter than what I consume

Hint:

> I am something real, something tangible that you can put your hands on, something that can become enormous.

Comment: I would have said the "like" button, but last one does not add up

Comment: @me_digvijay  check out my latest hint.  If it still doesn't add up then it will when you see the answer.  Give me the up click then.  :)

Comment: Does it get infinitely larger? Or does it have a maximum size ?

Comment: @Red fx  doesn't get infinitely larger but does get REALLY big almost the size of an island

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hazarding a guess you are

> an iceberg

I grow by consuming one thing

> Water - ocean icebergs are composed of mostly fresh water from the salty sea.

The more I consume the larger I get

> Yes

Regardless of my size you don't see more of me

> Only see 10% of you regardless of size - the tip of the iceberg.
>
>  Or the answer may be more like pond ice. If the surface is frozen over the ice layer will increase in depth but the visible top remains the same.

I am lighter than what I consume

> Ice is less dense than water.

Hint: I am something real, something tangible that you can put your hands on, something that can become enormous.

> Ice is tangible. It could be small like an ice cube or titanic.

Comment: Thanks due to you Dr T for the creativity and Rand for the breakthrough.

Comment: Ah, the third line was what tripped me up. @Drt You do see more of it in an absolute sense as it gets bigger, right? Just not *proportionally* more of it.

Comment: i could never let go off of the two word answer clue :P

Answer (score 8):

You are

> a sponge.

*I grow by consuming one thing*

> Water.

*The more I consume the larger I get*

> As a sponge becomes saturated, it gets heavier.

*Regardless of my size you don't see more of me*

> Regardless of the amount of water, the amount of sponge material remains the same.

*I am lighter than what I consume*

> A dry sponge is lighter than the same amount of water.

*I am something real, something tangible that you can put your hands on, something that can become quite heavy.*

> Well indeed.

---

**Previous answer**

<s>Are you</s>

> a balloon?

*I grow by consuming one thing*

> A balloon consumes gas to become larger.

*The more I consume the larger I get*

> Clearly.

*Regardless of my size you don't see more of me*

> No matter how large it gets, there's still the same amount of balloon material, just stretched thinner and wider.

*I am lighter than what I consume*

> Depends what kind of gas you put into it.

Comment: I don't think that last statement is true.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor  Thanks for the edit.  Check out my recently added hint.  An empty balloon would not be lighter than air or helium etc.  Good try though

Comment: @Drt Edited to change my answer after your hint.

Comment: @Gareth Fair point; I've now changed it to a different answer.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor   check for the change I made to the hint.  You are on track.  You are forcing me to purify my hint for the riddle.  thank you

Comment: ^ vote, although a sponge doesn't really consume anything, it merely holds liquid until it's squeezed out

Answer (score 3):

you are

> Sun light

I grow by consuming one thing

> you consume darkness

The more I consume the larger I get

> more things illuminated causes more light refraction, creating more lighted space

Regardless of my size you don't see more of me

> your sight is limited to the area of sunlight you can see, regardless of how much 'bigger' it gets

I am lighter than what I consume

> I may be taking some liberties here, but you are 'lighter' because you ARE light. which is 'lighter' than darkness:)

Comment: check out the new hint.  I like your literary license but it is off.

Answer (score 3):

The two words just means this is more specific, but you can madlib the first word to my guess which is:

> ______ virus (e.g. flu, ebola, etc.)

I grow by consuming one thing

> Healthy Cells.  Viruses live (e.g reproduce) by injecting their genetic material into a healthy cell which is then consumed to make more viruses

The more I consume the larger I get

> The more virus present the larger the infection and the more people infected/sick the larger the epidemic

Regardless of my size you don't see more of me

> It's a virus, you never "see" it as it exists at the microscopic level.

I am lighter than what I consume

> A virus is smaller than a cell and is often transported by physical contact/airborne transmission/etc which implies it's lighter than a cell.

Hint: I am something real, something tangible that you can put your hands on, something that can become enormous.

> A virus is quite real and tangible and often time is transmitted when you put your hands on it.  An epidemic, given the proper circumstances, can also become enormous.

Comment: Nice "out-of-the-box" answer!

Comment: @John Eisbrener     Wow!!  I never would have thought this would be an answer.  Nice shot at it.

Answer (score 2):

This might be way off but I want to say...

> **Forest Fire**

I grow by consuming one thing

> It consumes mostly one thing - wood

The more I consume the larger I get

> More wood it burns, bigger it gets

Regardless of my size you don't see more of me

> There are only few big forest fires every year

I am lighter than what I consume

> Fire is lighter then the wood it consumes

And...

> It is a two words answer

Comment: You are strangely kind of on target...just go the other direction...way the other direction

Comment: @Drt : is it snow-storm?

Comment: It isn't a snow storm but if you combine that thinking with what Rand al'Thor submitted and you will be oh so close!!  Yippeeee Yay

Comment: sponge storm? :D:D just kidding

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are

> A cloud ?

I grow by consuming one thing

> Grow in size by absorbing water

The more I consume the larger I get

> The more water comes in, the bigger it gets

Regardless of my size you don't see more of me

> ??? if "more of me" is used as "a bigger surface of me", could be because clouds grow in height (idk about this one ^^')

I am lighter than what I consume

> clouds fly

Hint | I am something real, something tangible that you can put your hands on, something that can become enormous.

> Not everybody can touch it, but it's made of water, which is tangible. And it can grow enormous as cloud can be kilometers long

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Fire

grow by consuming one thing

> It grows by consuming air

The more I consume the larger I get

> The more air it get, the more heavily it burns

Regardless of my size you don't see more of me

> The fire disappears as smoke upwards

I am lighter than what I consume

> Fire is lighter than air

Hint: 
I am something real, something tangible that you can put your hands on, something that can become enormous.

> Fire is tangible, and it burns enormously when someone or something comes in contact with it.

Comment: Guess we all though fire first, consume would be a huge hint, but if the fire is bigger in size you do see more fire right ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is a black hole.
It grows by consuming masses.
It gets larger in the process.
But since it is so heavy not even light can escape it and therefore you can not see it.
Since it radiates energy while absorbing masses via gravitational waves it is lighter than its components.

Comment: Okay, to make things clear there is no theory of quantum physics required for this one.  Nice try though.  It surprised me.  It made me smile.  Thank you lots.  t

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A hot air balloon

I grow by consuming one thing

> Air

The more I consume the larger I get

> Obviously

Regardless of my size you don't see more of me

> It gets larger but its amount doesn't change.

I am lighter than what I consume

> The weight of a hot air balloon is less than air. That's how they fly.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> cotton / cotton ball

I grow by consuming one thing

> Water

The more I consume the larger I get

> Becomes heavier

Regardless of my size you don't see more of me

> it remains same just stretches and consume water

I am lighter than what I consume

> lighter than water

I am something real, something tangible that you can put your hands on,

> True

something that can become enormous

> can stretch cotton

Answer (score 1):

It could be a

> Water bed

As,

> It grows in size by consuming water
>  though it grows by consuming water, we cannot see it more of it
>  Usually an empty water bed is much lighter than the water it can hold

Comment: this is not the right answer but i really like it.  Up vote for a fun answer

Answer (score 1):

Probably a big stretch but could this be a

> Star - or specifically a red dwarf?

I grow by consuming one thing

> flammable gasses?

The more I consume the larger I get

> I'm pretty sure some stars (or all?) grow in diameter as they shrink in mass

Regardless of my size you don't see more of me

> These stars are actually made up of less matter and emit less light so you kind of see less of them as they grow?

I am lighter than what I consume

> Lighter could mean emits more light?

Hint:

I am something real, something tangible that you can put your hands on, something that can become enormous.

> Real, tangible, ..., enormous.  Ok... so probably not but maybe-almost-ish